Why does my angular app hosted on nginx throw me an error 502 bad gateway error
Yo
I've been trying to host an Angular app on NGINX with Docker but when I build the container and go to localhost:8080 I get an 502 Bad Gateway error.
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:latest as build

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]

This is my docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

This is my default.conf file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

This is the line I'm using to build the image:
docker build -t front .

This is the line I'm using to run the image:
docker run -d -p 8080:80 front

I don't know what to do, I'm going crazy.
I need help with this

You need to use compose to start the container. Otherwise it won't be on the network that compose creates and then it won't be able to talk to the app container. Try docker compose up -d.

Hi Hans Kilian, thanks for the answer. the code throw this error:  2024/04/28 14:47:13 [error] 32#32: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: app, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:4200/favicon.ico", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"

The other important question is what npm start actually does in the Node container.  If it starts something like a Vite dev server that only listens on the container-private localhost interface, it won't be reachable from the other container.
